# button fixed in height with text in multiple rows do not show in same vertical position

Tags: css, button, height, word-wrap

#### button css fixed with height make the vertical position ugly as each button text are more than one row

I tried to comment the **height:80px;** then all buttons are aligned at top vertically, but all buttons will have different height, bring the **BUTTONS GROUP look ugly**, especially I need to generate over 10 pieces of button

```
button {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #444;
  width: 120px;
  height:80px !important;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px;
  margin: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```
<button>Text in one row </button>
<button>Text in more than one row in this button </button>
<button>Text in more than two rows in this button which have same height </button>
<button>Text in more than three rows in this button which have same height, but more text </button>
```

[CLICK to open an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6GfC.png)

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fc338339/g93tkm5v/4/)

#### How to have buttons fixed in height and all buttons locate vertically-top.  

Note: each button have different number of words, word-wrap into 1 line, 2 lines, 3 lines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `vertical-align: top;` to your `button` element this will resolve your problem

CSS

```
button {
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-weight: normal;
   color: #444;
   width: 120px;
   height: 80px;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 5px;
   margin: 5px 10px;
   background-color: #fdfdfd;
   border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
   cursor: pointer;
   border-radius: 3px;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

Run the code snippet below to see the result

```css
button {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #444;
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding:5px;
  margin: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<button>Text in one row </button>
<button>Text in more than one row in this button </button>
<button>Text in more than two rows in this button which have same height </button>
<button>Text in more than three rows in this button which have same height, but more text </button>
```